# Powershell getfiles.count() to exclude thumbs.db

Tags: powershell, getfiles

We have a script running daily that removes old files and directories from an area that people use to transfer data around.  Everything works great except for one little section.  I want to delete a folder if it's older than 7 days and it's empty. The script always shows 1 file in the folder because of the thumbs.db file.  I guess I could check to see if the one file is thumb.db and if so just delete the folder but I'm sure there is a better way.

```
 
$location = Get-ChildItem \\dropzone -exclude thumbs.db
foreach ($item in $location) {

  other stuff here going deeper into the tree...

  if(($item.GetFiles().Count -eq 0) -and ($item.GetDirectories().Count -eq 0)) {

    This is where I delete the folder but because the folder always has
     the Thumbs.db system file we never get here

  } 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$NumberOfFiles = (gci -Force $dir | ?{$_ -notmatch "thumbs.db"}).count
```

Comment: Ok, so the solution using this answer was this:

if(gci $item.FullName | ?{$_ -notmatch 'thumbs.db'}).count -le 0){
    Delete folder...
}

Comment: @murisonc I'm assuming that not having a second `(` after `if(` was an oversight in your comment and is correct in your code, but I will recommend including the `-Force` parameter as I have included in my answer, because without it `gci` will not find hidden files/folders. `gci -Force` functions similarly to `ls -A`

Comment: Your are correct on both parts.  However, I purposefully left out the -Force since this is a public share for people to exchange data and anything over 7 days old gets deleted by the script and if anyone tries to circumvent it with hidden folders it still gets deleted.  But that makes me think.  Since gci doesn't get hidden files I could just use if((gci $item.FullName).count -le 0) {Delete folder...}.  Is that correct since the Thumbs.db file is a hidden system file?

Comment: That is correct, provided the attributes have not been altered to make it non-hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the get-childitem -exclude option where all files/items in your directory will be 
counted except those that end in db:

```
$location = get-childitem -exclude *.db
```

It also works out if you specify the file to exclude, in this case thumbs.db

```
$location = get-childitem -exclude thumb.db
```

Let me know if this works out.

---

Ah, I also just noticed something,

```
$location = get-childitem -exclude *.db
```

Will only handle .db items in the location directory, if you're going deeper into the tree (say from your GetFiles() and GetDirectories() methods) then you may still find a thumb.db.  Hence you'll have to add the exclude option in these methods to ignore thumbs.db.

So, for example in your $item.getFiles() method, if you use get-childitem you will have to specify the -exclude option as well.

Sorry, I should have read your question more closely.

Comment: Added your suggestion to the code and it still doesn't work.  The line $item.GetFiles().Count still comes back with 1 and I verified the only file in the folder is Thumbs.db.

Comment: The file name might be case sensitive, is it thumbs.db or thumb.db (Captial T)?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to provide a exclusion list in the form of a simple text file to exclude specific files or extensions from your count:

```
$dir = 'C:\YourDirectory'
#Type one filename.ext or *.ext per line in this txt file
$exclude = Get-Content "C:\Somefolder\exclude.txt"
$count = (dir $dir -Exclude $exclude).count
$count
```